# Is it possible to create a separate folder for keeping images and sounds

Tags: android

Hi
I need to keep my images and their sounds on a separate folder inside res folder structure.After that i need to read and display image from that folder to my application
please reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save your images to res/drawable and your sound files to res/raw.

If you really want to create a separate folder for your sound and image files, you can create it on your SD Card. Please see the example codes below:

```
File fileList= new File("/sdcard/MyFiles/");
//Store the file names within MyFiles folder to pathList[]
pathList = fileList.list();

//Create the URI path of your files here
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("/sdcard/MyFiles/"+pathList[index1]);
pathList[index1]=sb.toString();

//Here is how you can play your sound files
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setDataSource(PATH_TO_FILE);
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** ,  You can create a separate folder named **raw** within **res** folder **(res/raw)** and keep your drawable and sounds in that folder.

Comment: can we create another two more folder inside that raw folder